# SQL CASE when text field is NULL not working

Tags: sql-server, null, conditional-statements, case

I'm trying to run the following case statement in SQL:

```
CASE 
    WHEN P.Photos_Cloned_From IS NULL
        THEN 'http://www.toolboxbarn.com/v/vspfiles/photos/'+P.ProductCode+'-2T.jpg'
        ELSE 'http://www.toolboxbarn.com/v/vspfiles/photos/'+P.Photos_Cloned_From+'-2T.jpg'
    END AS image_link,
```

The statements works, but only for those records that are not NULL.  For items that are NULL, the statement is not returning the THEN condition.

Any suggestions?

Comment: When you say "not returning the THEN condition", do you mean that the value being returned in the record is incorrect, or that it's missing entirely?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Maybe it's not null but just an empty string?

Comment: Matt, Hogan and Mansoor.  Thanks so much for your help.  I figured it out.  There was no code issue.  My user told me all the records were finished completed...but that was incorrect as I began dissecting the database.  All works fine now with the original code....but I did learn something from each of you.  Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this and let us know what happens.

```
'http://www.toolboxbarn.com/v/vspfiles/photos/'+
    COALESCE(P.Photos_Cloned_From,P.ProductCode,'DEFAULT')+'-2T.jpg'
AS image_link,
```

Using coalesce here is better than the case statement.  Some platforms can optimize coalesce and it lets you easily make a default value.

Comment: I like the suggestion, but ultimately it should be the same result as CASE WHEN NULL THEN ... ELSE ... is the same as COALESCE(THEN,ELSE)

Comment: @Matt - no I have a default after the 2nd option so this will fix the "both null" problem with the OP's code which I believe we both think is the problem.

Comment: true wasn't thinking about your 'default' as that would add a new case to the OP which may or may not be desired but as you say will eliminate the null which is likely the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

@hogan's Suggestion is a great one to save code, but ultimately it should have the same result as your case statement if you don't introduce his new 'default' case.  It is most likely that the `ProductCode` is also `NULL` is that a possibility?

Why `string + NULL = NULL` because NULL is an unknown in sql most db platforms will nullify the entire value when null is aggregated or concatenated.

So Think of the following test cases:

```
Id   ProductCode    Photos_Cloned_From
1    1               ClonedFrom
2    2               Null
3    NULL            Null
```

The results of your case expression and Hogan's Suggestion would be:

1) ELSE 'http://www.toolboxbarn.com/v/vspfiles/photos/ClonedFrom-2T.jpg'

2) WHEN 'http://www.toolboxbarn.com/v/vspfiles/photos/2-2T.jpg'

3) WHEN NULL

Comment: please look at my answer again, I don't fail the null, null case.

Comment: @Hogan true I did and I just read quickly, I did update my answer to state if the new case 'default' was not included results would be the same

Answer (score 0):

```
CASE WHEN ISNULL(P.Photos_Cloned_From,'') = '' THEN 'http://www.toolboxbarn.com/v/vspfiles/photos/'+P.ProductCode+'-2T.jpg'
    ELSE 'http://www.toolboxbarn.com/v/vspfiles/photos/'+P.Photos_Cloned_From+'-2T.jpg'
END AS image_link,
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
   F.Name
 , F.Address
 , F.InDate
 , ( CASE WHEN (F.Date_Down IS NULL and F.Cod_Down = 0 )THEN 0 ELSE -1 END) as 'sn_Down'
FROM
   Folders F
```